# SyntaxError: The requested module 'redux' does not provide an export named 'createStore'

Tags: redux

I was trying to run a simple redux application on Node.js version: 13.8.0

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type){
        case "ADD":
            state = state + action.payload;
            break;
        case "SUBTRACT":
            state = state - action.payload;
            break;
    }
    return state;
};

const store = createStore(reducer, 1);

store.subscribe(()=>{
    console.log("State changed. ", store.getState());
});

store.dispatch({
    type: "ADD",
    payload: 10
});
```

This gives the follwing error:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Then I added  ***"type": "module"*** to the *package.json* file and tried changing the file extension to *.mjs* and even tried both the changes together.
This gives the following error:

```
import { createStore } from "redux";
         ^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: The requested module 'redux' does not provide an export named 'createStore'
```

I found some similar errors on StackOverflow and modified accordingly but nothing helped.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm experiencing the exact same issue in my Jest test suite.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to run typescript as javascript.

Rename your file with a `.ts` extension (e.g. `app.ts`), compile it with `tsc app`, then run the resulting javascript with `node app`

Comment: Though I didn't even have ```tsc``` installed, I installed and tried to run as you suggested but it didn't work. Showing some different errors related to typescript.